Movie with black character turned in to a cyborg that sacrifices himself to save his buddies
I originally thought it might be the movie was Virus (1999), because it had the same struggle in it, in which cast members are converted in to meaty cyborgs. After watching Virus again, I realized it wasn't the movie I was looking for, so I decided to ask the internet for help.
I remember bad practical effects. They showed lots of close-ups on the actor's face to hide how bad the entire cyborg model looked. When able to see the full cyborg, they shot from a distance and in a dark area. Still, you can see that the cyborg was a cheesy looking meat machine.
The setting was industrial looking, but I'm not sure if it was supposed to take place in the future or space.
I swear he is supposed to be killing everyone, but fights the cyborg impulses to save his friends in the end. I also feel that he disappears midway through the movie, and you assume he is dead, only to come to the rescue at the end.
I believe it would be a live-action US film, and probably released in the 90s to 00s.
I can't provide a better description of the character, I only have a vague memory.

Country? Language? Release year/decade? How does character look? Anything else form the story?

It's better if you merge both your accounts, it will give you better control of your content. Refer here to do so.
